# Windows store Async BackgroundDownloader is not updating UI progress with number of file download correctly

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have list of images which I need to download. I am using BackgroundDownloader and DownloadOperation. I have placed progressbar to show the number of files downloaded. 
The UI always update 1 less than downloaded file. Can anyone please point where I am missing.

Here is the code:

***C#***

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    int count = 0;
    public StorageFile ErrorFile { get; set; }
    private List<DownloadOperation> activeDownloads = new List<DownloadOperation>();
    List<string> guid = new List<string>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        await StartDownload();
    }

    private async Task StartDownload()
    {
        BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        downloader.CostPolicy = BackgroundTransferCostPolicy.UnrestrictedOnly;
        List<Task> downloadCompletionTasks = new List<Task>();

        List<string> files = GetFiles();
        totalCount.Text = (files.Count).ToString();

        progressBar1.Maximum = (files.Count);

        foreach (string url in files)
        {
            StorageFile file = null;
            file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            DownloadOperation op = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(url), file);
            activeDownloads.Add(op);
        }

        //This forloop cannot be clubbed with above for loop because progressChanged event is accessing activeDownloads. 
        //In case of clubbing with above loop collection modified loop will be thrown.
        foreach (DownloadOperation op in activeDownloads)
        {
            Progress<DownloadOperation> progress = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(progressChanged);
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            downloadCompletionTasks.Add(op.StartAsync().AsTask(cancellationToken.Token, progress));
        }

        Task status = Task.WhenAll(downloadCompletionTasks);
    }



    private async void progressChanged(DownloadOperation downloadOperation)
    {
        foreach (DownloadOperation op in activeDownloads)
        {
            if (!guid.Contains(op.Guid.ToString()))
            {
                if (op.Progress.Status == BackgroundTransferStatus.Completed)
                {
                    await UpdateUI(downloadOperation, op);
                }
                else if (op.Progress.Status == BackgroundTransferStatus.Error)
                {
                    await UpdateUI(downloadOperation, op);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task UpdateUI(DownloadOperation downloadOperation, DownloadOperation op)
    {
        guid.Add(op.Guid.ToString());
        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
        {
            count = count + 1; //guid count can be used as well
            progressBar1.Value = count;
            progressCount.Text = count.ToString();
        });

    }

    private List<String> GetFiles()
    {
        List<string> imgurl = new List<string>();
        imgurl.Add("http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/26700000/Snoopy-peanuts-26798453-1024-768.jpg");
        imgurl.Add("http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Peanut-Wallpapers-peanuts-99522_1024_768.jpg");
        imgurl.Add("http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/25300000/peanuts-peanuts-25369428-800-600.jpg");
        imgurl.Add("http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/37200000/Peanuts-Movie-Wallpaper-peanuts-37225534-3996-2160.jpg");
        imgurl.Add("http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Peanut-Wallpapers-peanuts-99520_1024_768.jpg");
        imgurl.Add("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wU0ljNbhyUc/TYo-LLNzqiI/AAAAAAAACQU/YxAHEOAFfCk/s1600/snoopy+peanuts+desktop+wallpaper.jpg");
        imgurl.Add("http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/26700000/Peanuts-peanuts-26798652-1024-768.jpg");
        imgurl.Add("http://brandthunder.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Peanuts-Wallpaper.jpg");
        imgurl.Add("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OT_HLjvXiSM/UXbByYXDU3I/AAAAAAAAAdo/6kQv7OO0v4I/s1600/snoopy-woodstock_00392750.jpg");
        imgurl.Add("http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/33100000/Snoopy-wallpaper-snoopy-33124725-1024-768.jpg");

        return imgurl;
    }
}
```

***Xaml***

```
 <Grid Background="DarkBlue">
    <!--<Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.6" Grid.Row="0"/>-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Margin="50" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Downloading" x:Name="fileName" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar1"  IsIndeterminate="False" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <!--<TextBlock x:Name="percentTextBlock" Text="{Binding TotalProgressPercent}" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>-->

            <TextBlock FontSize="20" x:Name="progressCount" Text="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="left"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="20" x:Name="totalCount" Text="50" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a threading issue. Turn your guid collection into a HashSet. It's possible that the check to see if the guid is part of the list fails if the event is fired at the same time and the guid would be added multiple times. A HashSet will prevent the guid from being added twice.

Your count variable is not safe as it could be overwritten by calls to the method at the same time. You should use the new HashSet's count.

--Edit--

Since you already have a list of active downloads, just remove the one that completes like this:

```
private async void progressChanged(DownloadOperation downloadOperation)
{
    var status = downloadOperation.Progress.Status;

    if (status == BackgroundTransferStatus.Completed || status == BackgroundTransferStatus.Error)
    {
        await UpdateUI(downloadOperation);
    }
}

private async Task UpdateUI(DownloadOperation downloadOperation)
{
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
    {
        activeDownloads.Remove(downloadOperation);
        var activeCount = activeDownloads.Count;
        progressBar1.Value = activeCount;
        progressCount.Text = activeCount.ToString();
    });

}
```

Comment: Converting list into HashSet for Guid didn't work. The number of file download is correct only issues in updating UI with number of files downloaded.

Comment: Please see my updates. There is no reason to loop over your downloads and no reason to use the guid's. You already have a list of your active downloads so once a download isn't active, remove it from the list. Then your UpdateUI can just use that list's count.